# I am trying to grab this info and put it into a payload and send it to my API

Tags: javascript, bluetooth, popup, bluetooth-gatt

**Question/ Issues**
I have this code to get Bluetooth devices and cannot get it to not do a pop-up.   Is it possible to do something that has not gone into a pop-up?   As you can see from the code it is very simple and can use other calls or functions without having a pop-up but this one will not serve the response without it in a pop-up.

**Additional Question**
If this cannot be modified does anyone have any suggestions?

**Challenge**
I am trying to grab this info and put it into a payload and send it to my API.  However, from a popup, it is not easy, and not an expert on how to pull from pop-ups

**CODE**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <p>Click the button to get your Bluetooth.</p>
    
    <button onclick="getBluetooth()">Try It</button>
    
    <p id="Bluetooth"></p>
    
    <script>
    var x = document.getElementById("Bluetooth");
    function getBluetooth() {  
      navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
      acceptAllDevices: true,
      optionalServices: ['battery_service'] // Required to access service later.
    })
    .then(device => { /* … */ })
    .catch(error => { console.error(error); });
        
    }
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
    
    
    **/CODE**
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve a list of devices without the pop-up is not possible since this is done in browser side, and we just wait for the user interaction.

You can updater your `getBluetooth` function with this to get the user selected device:

```
function getBluetooth() {
  return navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
    acceptAllDevices: true,
    optionalServices: ["battery_service"],
  });
}

getBluetooth()
  .then((device) =>  console.log('Selected device', device))
  .catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help do you have any suggestions to which would be a better way to get this data, so I can send it out not a popup?